# Floating number calculations in bash

Tags: bash, math, floating-point

We have installed limited Linux edition where is no awk and bc installed.

There is script where time calculations are performed.

```
ms_date()
{
  date '+%s.%N' | sed 's/N$//'
}

stime=$(ms_date)    
#some code
etime=$(ms_date)
duration=$(echo ${etime} - ${stime} | bc)
```

Would you please advice what can be used for floating number calculations if bc and awk are not installed and couldn't be used?

Can it be done using expr or sed?

Thank you.

Comment: Find a comprehensive list here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/40596

Comment: You could try another interpreted language probably. And I'll choose Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use decimals until you have to display:

```
ms_date () { date +%s%N; }
display_time () { 
    if [[ $1 =~ ^([0-9]*)([0-9]{9})$ ]]; then
        printf "%s.%s\n" ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    fi
}

start=$(ms_date)
sleep 1
end=$(ms_date)
duration=$( display_time $((end - start)) )
```

Comment: Hello Glenn, thank you. It works if you have sleep 1 as you have specified. If you omit sleep then the number of numbers in variable passed to display_time will be less than 9 but in such case we can specify 0 in from on the number and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Bash can't handle floating point calculations but it looks like you could get away integer arithmetic.  Just do away with the decimal and calc in nanoseconds.

`duration=$(($etime - $stime))`